# What's a simple way of having a polymorphic @ViewChildren selector in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

A part of a small Angular app of mine has a set of UI elements that I want to query with @ViewChildren. They would not the same component or directive, but share some common traits (e.g. a common function to call).

The code I've got does work, but it grew a bit with my attempts. So right now my set of Gadgets alls have the same `IGadget` interface, derive from the same `AbstractGadget` class and then are configured to use provides: `{ provide: AbstractGadget, useExisting: ThisGadget }`. Apparently the latter is really needed by the `@ViewChildren` implementation, as it doesn't know of any kind of language level polymorphism.

Sample code on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hktbci?file=src/app/gadgets.component.ts

Pertinent part:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'first-gadget',
  providers: [{ provide: AbstractGadget, useExisting: FirstGadget }],
})
class FirstGadget extends AbstractGadget implements IGadget
```

I'm not using the result in the same manner as in the sample code, by the way. The question here is just about getting the verbosity of the `@ViewChildren` part down, so the UI usage there is just for illustrative purposes. My production system uses Angular 12 right now, but upgrading wouldn't be an issue if it would help here.

I was looking at some really old github issues, and at least back then it was because the DI that's used for the `ViewChildren` tokens doesn't know about inheritance. Partly because the Dart implementation of Angular couldn't use that.
But all that was a few years ago, and both TypeScript and Angular changed a bit since then, so maybe there's a better way.

Comment: Could you not use a template selector `#whatever` and set the type to your base class and then coerce to a different type when you need to?

Comment: Could you explain in a different way what you are expecting?

Comment: Template references as selectors would of course work, but that would only make things more complicated/manual. With a base class and manual providers it does work, I'm just hoping for a simpler yet typesafe solution.

Comment: Expecting from this question or in code? Here, I'm *hoping* for a simpler solution than excessive annotations for classes.
In the code, I'm expecting ViewChildren to result in a QueryList with all instances of components of the same "family" (this probably means inheritance in TS/JS). I get that right now, but with a bit of redundant information necessary.